# unresolved symbols reported by nm

Tags: c++, linker

I am compiling my code to create a shared library and finally linking them to the correct libraries(shared libraries). However when i view my shared library with "nm -u" it shows unresolved symbols, mainly from (libm.so and libstdc++.so). I have compiled it with the flags -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--no-undefined-version but during linking it doesnot report anything.

Are these symbols reported by nm for libm and libstdc++  intended?
Please note that i am cross compiling for QNX OS.

Thanks in advance and kind Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are these symbols reported by nm for libm and libstdc++ intended?

Yes: when you link against *shared* libraries, the symbols stay unresolved. They get bound to the definition in the shared library at *runtime*. That's what it *means* to link dynamically against other libraries.

Update:

> i find other unresolved symbols too say for libsocket.so. It looks like this:
>   `U connect@@libsocket.so.2`
>   But the symbol for math libraries is like this:
>   `U pow`
>   Why is this difference even though all these are shared libraries.

This is because `connect` in `libsocket` is a versioned symbol, but `pow` in `libm` is not. You can read about versioned symbols [here](http://lists.debian.org/lsb-spec/1999/12/msg00017.html).

> there is another shared library, to which when i link it shows this symbol:
>   `W _ZN15HWPos15getCCount`
>   Why is there this difference?

This is a weakly-defined symbol, not an unresolved one. You can read about weak ELF symbols [here](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/42).

Comment: thank you for the reply... :). Though that does bring me to one question i find other unresolved symbols too say for libsocket.so. It looks like this : "U connect@@libsocket.so.2"  But the symbol for math libraries is like this: "U pow".  Why is this difference even though all these are shared libraries.

Comment: Also there is another shared library, to which when i link it shows this symbol: "W _ZN15HWPos15getCCount". Why is there this difference?